# LINQ Join on multiple columns with different record using extension method syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, self-join

Sorry, if my question doesn't make much sense. Let me explain.

I have an existing SQL query as below:

```
 SELECT 
     T1.Portfolio, T1.ValueDate as CurrentValueDate, 
     T1.DifferencePercent as CurrentDP, 
     T2.ValueDate as PreviousValueDate, 
     T2.DifferencePercent as PreviousDP,
     CASE 
        WHEN T1.DifferencePercent = T2.DifferencePercent 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
     END as IsChange
 FROM 
     [AccountingData].[dbo].[NAVRec_NAVSummary] T1
 JOIN 
     [AccountingData].[dbo].[NAVRec_NAVSummary] T2 ON T1.Portfolio = T2.Portfolio AND T2.ValueDate = DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, T1.ValueDate) WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, T1.ValueDate))
```

So basically, I'm interested in displaying the portfolio's along with a column which tells whether the portfolio's `DifferencePercent` value has changed from the value for the same portfolio on the previous business day.

I'm trying to translate the same sql query into LINQ using extension method syntax. However, right now I'm just trying to make a self join using the Portfolio property AND the ValueDate of today's Portfolio and ValueDate of the same portfolio on a previous business date.

```
var result = NavList.Join(NavList, 
                            outer => new { outer.Portfolio, outer.ValueDate }, 
                            inner => new { inner.Portfolio, PD = inner.ValueDate.PreviousBusinessDate() }, 
                            (outer, inner) => new { outer, inner });
```

[PreviousBusinessDate() is an extension method that returns a DateTime]

Here, I get an error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func, System.Func, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Can someone help me understand the problem and the solutions.

Comment: *"The type arguments for method .... "* - you didn't include the **most important** information - the **name of the method**. Also, I don't know if it's related, but you cannot use extension method inside a projection **expression**.

Comment: What do exactly mean by the name of the method ? The error is thrown for the Join method.

Comment: Again, the error message is *"The type arguments for **method**..."*. Which method?? You have 2 methods in that code snippet - `Join` and your custom extension method. I mean, when you have a problem, include the whole exception message, most of the time the answer is there.

Comment: Anyway, if you remove `.PreviousBusinessDate() ` (just for testing), do you still get an error?

Comment: Sorry for that @IvanStoev, I've posted the complete error message now. If I replace "PD = inner.ValueDate.PreviousBusinessDate()" with just "inner.ValueDate", then there is no error.

Comment: No problem. Just to be sure, `NavList` is `IQueryable<Something>`, right? (not `IEnumerable`, `List` etc)

Comment: I change it to this "NavList.AsQueryable<NavSummary>().Join()" but there is still the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102741/discussion-between-ivan-stoev-and-lucifer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here

```
outer => new { outer.Portfolio, outer.ValueDate }, 
inner => new { inner.Portfolio, PD = inner.ValueDate.PreviousBusinessDate() },
```

You are projecting anonymous types, and they need to match exactly. In order to match, the anonymous types must have exactly the same signatures, which include both property **name**s and their **type**.

In your case you didn't specify explicitly most of the property names, so the above is equivalent to

```
outer => new { Portfolio = outer.Portfolio, ValueDate = outer.ValueDate }, 
inner => new { Portfolio = inner.Portfolio, PD = inner.ValueDate.PreviousBusinessDate() },
```

See the difference? The second member in the first line is called `ValueDate` while in the second - `PD`.

Just replace the `PD` with `ValueDate` and the problem will be solved (for now).

Comment: Ahhh..so silly of me. Thanks @Ivan. Really appreciate your help.